# java.lang.NullPointerException with variable having a value (Eclipse)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have looked throughout the web to try to find an answer to my error, but nothing I have found matches my error or I fail to understand the relation.

Here is my error running on eclipse:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       ca.sheridancollege.controllers.CarDealership.doGet(CarDealership.java:63)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

and here is my code:

```
package ca.sheridancollege.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CarDealership
 */
@WebServlet("/CarDealership")
public class CarDealership extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public CarDealership() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dbURL= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SheridanUsedCars";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "1234";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String retrieve = "SELECT manufacturerID, manufacturer, price FROM car INNER JOIN manufacturer GROUP BY manufacturerID";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(retrieve);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println("Error executing "+ps.toString());
    try {
        while (rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("manufacturerID");
            String man = rs.getString("manufacturer");
            response.getWriter().append("<h1>"+id+" "+man+"</h1>");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

it seems to me like it thinks rs is null, is it because of the try catch? I cant seem to get it going.
any help is *really* appreciated

Comment: What happens when you put the code of the second try catch in the first try catch? This would make more sence

Comment: `rs` is not mentioned anywhere in the error message.  Have you tried looking at its value with a debugger?

Comment: If I'm counting right, line 63 is `while (rs.next()){`, so I'd have to agree with @RobertHarvey said.

Comment: Just a little note. You will never get a `NullPointerException` if the value is not null..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in here

```
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.err.println("Error executing "+ps.toString());
try {
    while (rs.next()){
```

If the call to executeQuery throws an exception, rs will stay null.  Since the try-catch block doesn't stop execution, it'll continue on despite rs being null, leading you to your error at line 63

Comment: so what you are saying is that the sql query is not correct?

Comment: That is most likely the problem here.  I would try and run the sql command in standalone sql and see if it succeeds. Alternatively, watch your errstream to see what the error is, since you print it with `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 2):

`rs` is `null` because `rs = ps.executeQuery();` fails. The exception should be written to the standard output - there must be another error visible before the NullPointerException occurs.

I think there is something wrong with your SQL query:

```
SELECT manufacturerID, manufacturer, price FROM car INNER JOIN manufacturer GROUP BY manufacturerID
```

because it doesn't specify the JOIN condition. It should be something like

```
SELECT manufacturerID, manufacturer, price
  FROM car INNER JOIN manufacturer
    ON car.manufacturerID = manufacturer.manufacturerID
  GROUP BY manufacturerID
```

(but I don't know for sure as I need the database structure for that. I'll hope you can figure this out on your own.)

Comment: hmmm ill try working with the query alone to verify i get an output.

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet rs` is never being set to anything other than `null` if an `SQLException` is being thrown. I'm guessing your query isn't returning what you are expecting. The tables that you are trying to join should share a column, try adding an `ON` statement in your query and use that column.

Try something like this: `INNER JOIN manufacturer ON table1.sharedColumn = table2.sharedColumn`

If that doesn't work I'd try using software like HeidiSQL so that you can connect to your database and run the query manually to see if it is returning data. It is much easier to tweak / test queries that way.